# TFS to VSTS Migration Guide: stated limit of 300 projects

Tags: tfs, migration, azure-devops

The TFS to VSTS Cloud Migration Guide contains the below **Project Limits** paragraph. Can "project" in the context of the below stated VSTS limitation equate to "git repository"? We have an on-prem collection with 323 git repositories in it already and I want to be certain if the below limitation applies to our situation and would cause us to have to split our collection in order to move to VSTS.

> ### Project Limits
>
> Customers with a large numbers of projects in a collection should note that VSTS has a limit of 300 projects per account. Above 300 projects certain experiences, such as connecting to the account from Visual Studio, start to degrade. If your collection has more than 300 projects then you will either need to split the collection or delete older projects to get below the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Team Projects are not the same thing as Git repositories. If you have 323 Team Projects, each with one Git repo, then yes, it applies. If you have 1 Team Project with 323 Git repos, no, it doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

There is a soft limit of about 300 Team Projects per Team Project Collection. Unlike TFS, there is only one project collection in VSTS for now. A related uservoice：

> **Let us create multiple collections on Visual Studio Team Services**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/3473653-let-us-create-multiple-collections-on-visual-studi

So the project here  means **Team Project**.  The scope of a team project should be things that are related to each other. When you work on a product that is very closely related you want to have everything in a single team project. Usually we wouldn't create so many team projects, 300 is a large number of it.
For more info about team project, you could refer this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/create-team-project?tabs=vsts) in MSDN.

**Git repositories is not equal to team projects**, multiple git repositories  may only belong to one team project. So you don't need to pay attention to how many git repositories do you have in your on-prem collection, just pay attention to the number of team projects.